# Add a web browser in my Java application

Tags: java, browser

I have a java application which is for viewing content from web. So I want to add a fully functional browser in my application. I've already tried `JEditorPane` and it's not processing dynamic contents. Is there any other way?

Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This links are good examples for this:

1. [create browser in swing](http://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emarkidis/lab3.html)
2. [how-to-create-a-simple-browser-in-swing](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-simple-browser-in-swing-3.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I already mention that I've already tried those example. and the JEditorPane can't handle modern javascript & css (Some old javascript and css are supported). So any other suggestion?

Comment: @Shaiful: If this is the case then you should need to override JEditorPane to support modern CSS and JS.

Comment: I want to keep it simple. Anyway, any help on overriding. Example or tutorial?

Comment: @Shaiful: [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JEditorPane.java) is the source for JEditorPane which can help you in understanding default operations so you can easily override them. Its for JDK6.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay for third party software you might want to consider JxBrowser:
http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/