# Show webpage in java editorPane

Tags: java, swing, html, jeditorpane

I want to show webpage in Java on Jframe using JeditorPane
code I used:

```
 edPane.setContentType("text/html"); 
    String data="<html>\n" + "<head>\n" + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script>\n" + 
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" + "  function initialize() \n" + "  {\n" + "              \n" + "    
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"map_canvas\"), myOptions);\n" + "</script>\n" + "</head>\n" + "<body onload=\"initialize()\">\n" + 
"  <div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width:100%; height:100%\"></div>\n" + "</body>\n" + "</html>";         edPane.setText(data);
```

Ouutput:
It is displaying nothing in UI..
I want to display the webpage...
Help please

Comment: Try looking at [this page][1] it has a very similar question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176806/add-a-web-browser-in-my-java-application

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm All you need

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that JEditorPane has no Javascript or HTML5 (canvas) support, so you should use another container.
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support) where the solution was moving to JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [**The DJ Project**](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html).

It is open source and released under [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License).

The `JWebBrowser` also provides the functionality to execute javascript code. Sample code as follows:

```
private static final String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");

JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
webBrowser.setStatusBarVisible(true);
final String htmlContent =
  "<html>" + LS +
  "  <body>" + LS +
  "    <h1>Some header</h1>" + LS +
  "    <p>A paragraph with a <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a>.</p>" + LS +
  "  </body>" + LS +
  "</html>";
webBrowser.setHTMLContent(htmlContent);

// [...] Add webBrowser to a container
webBrowser.executeJavascript("document.bgColor = '#FFFF00';");
```

Please see the project page for more samples.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend embedding JavaFX WebView rather than using a native library like DJ Project. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438201/pure-java-html-viewer-renderer/21459668#21459668). I also mention some problems I had with dj project, when it comes to platform independence.

Answer (score 0):

By Using a `JEditorPane` to display a web page:

```
 import javax.swing.text.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.*;

public class GoogleHomePage {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
     jep.setEditable(false);   

     try {
       jep.setPage("http://www.google.com");
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
       jep.setContentType("text/html");
       jep.setText("<html>Could not load http://www.google.com </html>");
     } 

     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
     JFrame f = new JFrame("O'Reilly & Associates");
     // Next line requires Java 1.3
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
     f.setSize(512, 342);
     f.show();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to show pages stored in local disk in a JEditorPane on Windows

1. create a website in IIS
2. the website should have folders associated with the pages.
3. put the web address into the setPage() function of JEditorPane

You are done.

The benefit of this approach is that you can keep your pages separate from application and protect them from write changes from the application.

Usually you cannot put relative address of webpage or an address without protocol into setPage() function. The above approach that I mentioned gives you both benefit of relative addresses and a protocol.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have `HTML` show up in a `JEditorPane`. One method is to create a `HTML` page. You have 2 options:

1. Put your `HTML` file on a clout like *DropBox* or *Google Drive*.
2. Have it locally in a File.

   ```
       JEditorPane editorPane_WEB = new JEditorPane();
       editorPane_WEB.setEditable(false); //OPTIONAL
       editorPane_WEB.setBorder(null); //OPTIONAL
       try {
           editorPane_WEB.setPage("http://---------------.com/--.html"); //Or Path/File destination
       } catch (IOException error) {/*ERROR*/}   

       JScrollPane scrollPane_WEB = new JScrollPane(editorPane_WEB);
       scrollPane_WEB.setBounds(67, 27, 798, 465); // Don't use null layout.
       scrollPane_WEB.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

       add(scrollPane_WEB); //class extends JFrame/JPanel
   ```

If this doesn't awnser you question, don't downvote, just put a comment below!

Comment: OP's HTML code includes Javascript (google maps API) and requires a canvas, so HTML5 and a modern Javascript engine is needed to render it. JEditorPane has an old HTML viewer with no JS engine

Comment: @PabloLozano yeah your right. Java should get a clean up of its existing code and make a bit more up to date.